# Laravel 8 set login session lifetime to a duration coming from DB

Tags: php, authentication, session, laravel-8, session-cookies

I have Laravel 8 app , I want to set the login session lifetime for each user as set in his row in DB , I tried doing this by using middleware as follow , but didn't worked

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userId = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : null;
        $defaultDuration = 7;
        $userDuration = User::where('id', $userId)->value('session_lifetime') ?? $defaultDuration;
        $sessionDuration = ($userDuration * 1440);
        config(['session.lifetime' => $sessionDuration]);
        return $next($request);
    }
```